# using require inside a class

Tags: php, oop, class

i want to make a "loader class" that will require selected files.

so i just can call eg. loader::load('systemLibraries, 'applicationLibraries').

so inside this load() method i will use require. but i have tried this and it seems that the files required can't be used outside the class.

how can i make it globally accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
class Loader{

    function load($class_name)
    {
         require($class_name ".php");
    }
}

Loader::load("MyClass");
$class = new MyClass;
```

Given that MyClass is in "MyClass.php"

This on the other hand, won't work

```
class Loader{

    function load($class_name)
    {
         require($class_name ".php");
         $class = new $class_name;
    }
}

Loader::load("MyClass");
$class->doSomething();
```

If `include.php` looks like this

```
$var = "Hi";
```

You can't do this:

```
Loader::load("include");
echo $var;
```

As there are scope issues.

You are going to need to give us more information on exactly **what** you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Chacha pointed out, make sure that you create the instance of the classes outside of your loader class. And since you have used the term **system libraries** which are usually always needed by the system, you can use the [__autoload magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to included them all automatically for you.